# Android app UI isn't displaying properly on physical device, unlike emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I'm getting into Android development and making a calculator.

The application works properly on a Pixel 3a emulator, but when I try it on my physical Samsung with Android 8.1 the UI isn't what it's supposed to be. The text on the buttons isn't showing, the buttons do appear as if they are being pressed when I press them, and the TextView is updating.

Layout:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/formula"
            style="@style/Formula"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:text="1-1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/result"
            style="@style/Result"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="0" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.25"/>

    <androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttons_layout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:columnCount="4"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:rowCount="5">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/clear"
            style="@style/MyButton.Additional"
            android:text="C" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/parenthesis"
            style="@style/MyButton.Additional"
            android:text="()" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/backspace"
            style="@style/MyButton.Additional"
            android:foreground="@drawable/backspace"
            android:foregroundGravity="center"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/division"
            style="@style/MyButton.Arithmetic"
            android:text="/" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/number_seven"
            style="@style/MyButton"
            android:text="7" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/number_eight"
            style="@style/MyButton"
            android:text="8" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/number_nine"
            style="@style/MyButton"
            android:text="9" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/multiplication"
            style="@style/MyButton.Arithmetic"
            android:text="*" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/number_four"
            style="@style/MyButton"
            android:text="4" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/number_five"
            style="@style/MyButton"
            android:text="5" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/number_six"
            style="@style/MyButton"
            android:text="6" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/subtraction"
            style="@style/MyButton.Arithmetic"
            android:text="-" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/number_one"
            style="@style/MyButton"
            android:text="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/number_two"
            style="@style/MyButton"
            android:text="2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/number_three"
            style="@style/MyButton"
            android:text="3" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/addition"
            style="@style/MyButton.Arithmetic"
            android:text="+" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/positive_negative"
            style="@style/MyButton"
            android:text="00" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/number_zero"
            style="@style/MyButton"
            android:text="0" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/decimal"
            style="@style/MyButton"
            android:text="." />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/total"
            style="@style/MyButton.Result"
            android:text="=" />

    </androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Logcat shows:

```
2021-01-20 07:23:55.156 16582-16582/? E/libpersona: scanKnoxPersonas
2021-01-20 07:23:55.156 16582-16582/? E/libpersona: Couldn't open the File - /data/system/users/0/personalist.xml - No such file or directory
2021-01-20 07:23:55.161 16582-16582/? W/SELinux: SELinux selinux_android_compute_policy_index : Policy Index[2],  Con:u:r:zygote:s0 RAM:SEPF_SAMSUNG-SM-J727A_8.1.0_0004, [-1 -1 -1 -1 0 1]
2021-01-20 07:23:55.162 16582-16582/? I/SELinux: SELinux: seapp_context_lookup: seinfo=untrusted, level=s0:c512,c768, pkgname=org.obebeokeke.calculator 
2021-01-20 07:23:55.166 16582-16582/? I/zygote: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2021-01-20 07:23:55.229 16582-16582/? D/TimaKeyStoreProvider: TimaKeyStore is not enabled: cannot add TimaSignature Service and generateKeyPair Service
2021-01-20 07:23:55.229 16582-16582/? D/ActivityThread: Added TimaKeyStore provider
2021-01-20 07:23:55.492 16582-16582/org.obebeokeke.calculator I/zygote: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$2>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/view/View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener;
2021-01-20 07:23:55.492 16582-16582/org.obebeokeke.calculator I/zygote:     at void androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.setBackground(android.view.View, android.graphics.drawable.Drawable) (ViewCompat.java:2678)
2021-01-20 07:23:55.492 16582-16582/org.obebeokeke.calculator I/zygote:     at void androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarContainer.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (ActionBarContainer.java:63)
2021-01-20 07:23:55.492 16582-16582/org.obebeokeke.calculator I/zygote:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:-2)
2021-01-20 07:23:55.492 16582-16582/org.obebeokeke.calculator I/zygote:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:334)
2021-01-20 07:23:55.492 16582-16582/org.obebeokeke.calculator I/zygote:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:647)
2021-01-20 07:23:55.492 16582-16582/org.obebeokeke.calculator I/zygote:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:790)
2021-01-20 07:23:55.492 16582-16582/org.obebeokeke.calculator I/zygote:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:730)
2021-01-20 07:23:55.492 16582-16582/org.obebeokeke.calculator I/zygote:     at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:863)
2021-01-20 07:23:55.492 16582-16582/org.obebeokeke.calculator I/zygote:     at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:824)
2021-01-20 07:23:55.492 16582-16582/org.obebeokeke.calculator I/zygote:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:515)
2021-01-20 07:23:55.492 16582-16582/org.obebeokeke.calculator I/zygote:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:423)
2021-01-20 07:23:55.492 16582-16582/org.obebeokeke.calculator I/zygote:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup) (LayoutInflater.java:374)
```

[This is what I'm supposed to see/what I am seeing in the emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOY62.png)

[This is what I see on the physical device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAa9u.jpg)

EDIT 1:

I have tried invalidating cache/restarting, I also restarted my PC and phone, no change.

EDIT 2:

My friend tried it in his phone and it worked, so somethings wrong with my phone.

Comment: can we see screenshot?

Comment: Added screenshot to post.

Comment: Did you checked in another emulator type phone (like Nexus 5, Pixel 2, etc)? Maybe it gives us some clue. Maybe it can be a resolution problem.

Comment: I just tried in a Galaxy Nexus with API 29, because it has the same resolution as my phone (720 x 1920), and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a factory reset on my phone and it worked, no idea why it wasn't.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just invalidate chaches and restart?

Comment: I tried that, as well as restarting PC and phone, no change.